# "unable to get local issuer certificate" with GlobalSign signed certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, ca

I have a wildcard certificate signed by GlobalSign for `bar.com` domain (`bar.com.crt` and `bar.com.key`).

I concatenate intermediate and root GlobalSign certificates to get the bundle of my `bar.com` certificate.

```
cat intermediate.crt root.crt > bundle.crt
```

I check the full chain is OK. This:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile bundle.crt bar.com.crt
```

Give me:

```
bar.com.crt: OK
```

Now, I want to sign a new certificate for `foo.bar.com` domain with my wildcard. I create the new bundle:

```
cat bar.com.crt bundle.crt > fullbundle.crt
```

Then I generate and sign the new certificate with:

```
openssl genrsa -out foo.bar.com.key 2048

openssl req -new -sha256 -key foo.bar.com.key -subj "/C=AA/ST=BB/L=CC/O=DD/CN=foo.bar.com" -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf '\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:%s,DNS:%s' "foo.bar.com" "anotherdns")) -out foo.bar.com.csr

openssl x509 -req -in foo.bar.com.csr -CA fullbundle.crt -CAkey bar.com.key -CAcreateserial -out foo.bar.com.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

But now, when I verify the new full chain:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile fullbundle.crt foo.bar.com.crt
```

Give me:

```
C = AA, ST = BB, L = CC, O = DD, CN = foo.bar.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error foo.bar.com.crt: verification failed
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I just can't sign new certificate with my wildcard. The certificate used to sign must have some extensions (https://serverfault.com/questions/749741/generate-subdomain-certificate-from-valid-wildcard-certificate).